# How to avoid having duplicate Option in HTML Select Multiple when trying to do an update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, jquery-select2, multiple-select

I have an html Select Multiple element containing a list of options. When trying to do an update, how to avoid having duplicates as shown on this capture:

[image: select multiple with duplicates]

Here I made a for loop to get A & C from database and add them as selected disabled element but they also appears in the select default options. How to avoid having that and have them instead only selected each once in the list?

```
select(class="form-control" id="select-license" name="license" multiple
              data-plugin="select2"  style="width: 100%")
                -for(var i = 0; i < requirements.license.length; i++)
                  <option value"#{requirements.license[i]}" selected disabled>#{requirements.license[i]}</option>
                <option value="Indifférent">Indifférent</option>
                <option value="A"> A</option>
                <option value="B"> B</option>
                <option value="C"> C</option>
                <option value="D"> D</option>
                <option value="E"> E</option>
```

This code is in Jade/Pug.
I will be thankful if anyone of you can help me with this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some of your code in which you update the multi select element.

Comment: Yes! I Have added the multi select code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `possible_options` variable consists of A, B, C, D and E.
And make function `inrequirements()`.

```
             select(class="form-control" id="select-license" name="license" multiple
              data-plugin="select2"  style="width: 100%")
                -for(var i = 0; i < possible_options.length; i++)
                   -if(inrequirements(i))
                    <option value"#{possible_options[i]}" selected disabled>#{possible_options[i]}</option>
                   -else
                    <option value"#{possible_options[i]}">#{possible_options[i]}</option>
```

Comment: Thank you @AkiraSuzuki for your answer, it looks like something that should solve my problem. Will try it.